# Form array gets sent full but received partially

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, post, multidimensional-array

I'm sending a large form over to server.

Now watching the developer tools i see :
[image]

As in 560 rows has been sent, but when I `print_r($_POST)`
I see only 500 rows.

Now I have tried setting :

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '1024M');
```

And I have `post_max_size` set to 8M and increasing it didn't seem to work either.
Also tried setting `max_input_vars` to 1000000 but same result.

I am submiting the form via ajax using jQuery. I'm getting same results with Chrome and FF

Any idea what may cause this?

This is the client side script :

```
    $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: { data : fullTableToJson($('#charges_table').get(0)),title : "sometitle"},
    url: 'url with get parameters',
    success : function(result) {    

    }
});
```

`fullTableToJson` is a method that turns html table to json, it works as i've been using it in many places in my code.

Could it be related to the fact my url contains GET parameters?

Comment: What's the client side script ?

Comment: if you think post_max_size is the culprit here and not able to increase it means you have to check your server.is it shared hosting? because shared hosting may have cap on max sizes.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7658193/is-there-any-size-limitation-for-ajax-post

Comment: It's not it's my server and no such blocking exist, in no way i don't believe an array of 560x6 should reach 8M

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, the problem was I had `max_input_vars` set to 3000, and I've tried sending 560x6 items which is 3360 items, which explains the leap.

Now i've tried changing it with

```
ini_set('max_input_vars', 999999);
```

And assumed it didn't solved it, but checking `phpinfo();` I saw that it hasn't changed.

Thus changed in php.ini file and it worked.