# Saving image from a canvas with php

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, canvas, fabricjs

I wanna save the canvas as png. The size of the canvas is about 2000x2000px, `canvas.toDataURL()` returns 5.600.000 chars (700 KB). When I try to send it to the server, I get an `413 request entity too large` error. There [isn't](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7658193/is-there-any-size-limitation-for-ajax-post#7658239) any size limit for ajax post. [In the server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9691057/php-apache-ajax-post-limit/9691395#9691395), the LimitRequestBody is 2 GB, more than I need, post_max_size is 132M.
Any idea, why I get this error?
Or are there a better way to save the image? I use fabric.js. I tried to draw the image with php, but I had many problems. Do you know any frameworks that can draw the same as the fabric.js?

Comment: Assuming you've tested your upload code with a smaller file and that test succeeded, be sure you’ve configured your php server with appropriate upload limits: post_max_size, upload_max_filesize,  max_execution_time.

Comment: post_max_size is more than I need. upload_max_filesize isn't essential, I'm not uploading any file (but it's 2000M lol). max_execution_time is 60. And yes, I tested it with a smaller image. When the canvas was about 750x750, it worked well, I could save the image.

Comment: Ok...is your upload directory set to other than the tmp directory and does that upload directory have sufficient disk space.  You might try to reduce the size of post_max_size to something reasonable(maybe 16M). Are you running other components (like nginx) that need to be configured also?  Realistically, it's very difficult to diagnose network config problems on a forum like stackoverflow...

Comment: 5,600,000 chars is not 700KB, it is ~ 5.5MB, how did you calculate it?

Answer (score 1):

You don't have acess to your server php.ini, right?

Try use [ini_set](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php) function:

For example:

```
ini_set('post_max_size', '10M');
ini_set('upload_max_filesize', '10M');
ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);
```

Or try put a `.htaccess` file in the same directory as your .php:

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 10M
php_value post_max_size 10M
php_value max_execution_time 0
```

Please note that 0 (zero) is infinite in `max_execution_time`.

I hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

you can go to the php.ini file and resize the max_post_lenght

Comment: There is no such php configuration variable.