# How to increase the maximum of JSON response

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, maxlength

Hello i have a webservice which response a json string to user and have set to max size of serialize the object.

```
WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
        byte[] buffer = webClient.DownloadData(url);

        PhotoData p1 = new PhotoData();
        p1.data = Convert.ToBase64String(buffer);

        JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        js.MaxJsonLength = Int32.MaxValue;
        string strJSON = js.Serialize(p1);

        return strJSON;
```

I can use the browser to try out the webservice and get the xml response correctly.. When I called using $.ajax i have an error saying about the maximum size of json reach. Do I have to set something on the $.ajax part?

Comment: Read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7658193/is-there-any-size-limitation-for-ajax-post

Comment: What other place do i need to set on the server... coz i already put that on the above code.